# Reprojection doesn't change the coordinates

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

Following the StackOverflow guidance, I have reprojected raster layers into WGS84/UTM 36N using the Raster-> Warp -> Reproject tool. According to the Raster Properties, all the rasters are now in the same CRS; however, the coordinate system is different and the rasters do not overlap (even though "On The Fly Projection" is on). Here are two screenshots of the problematic rasters with the different coordinates:

[image]

[image]

Based on comments from other threads, I understand that the units for the UTM projections is meters; however, the re-projection doesn't seem to properly changing the coordinate units. One remains in longitude/latitute while the other is in decimal degrees. Based on advice online, I have tried starting from scratch to ensure that the Map Project projection is correct, but nothing appears to work. Does anyone have any ideas? I am using QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have the raster been overlapping before you reprojected them?

Comment: Open New QGIS Project, turn off the `On The Fly Projection` and load the reprojected data, can you check if the data is in UTM coordinates with correct location?

Comment: Hi Eric - Yes, the layers did overlap originally prior to the reprojection.

Comment: Hi @ahmadhanb - I turned off the OTF projection and reloaded the reprojected data. According to the properties of each layer, they are all in the right CRS (+proj=utm +zone=36 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs), but they do have different coordinate units.

Comment: Can you confirm that your data does not cross two UTM zones like 36 and 37 for example? If they cross two zones, in this case, you need to reproject your data to take into consideration the UTM zone that is located in.

Comment: @ahmadhanb Interesting - you are right, my data crosses the UTM 36N and 37N line. How can I take into account both zones for a single raster? Do I just choose one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is crossing two UTM zones 36N and 37N, and assuming you have two images, you have three options:

- If the two images are separate and each image is located in a different zone, then reproject each one with its correct UTM zone.
- If the two images are merged together (mosaic image), then choose one of the zones such as UTM 37N, since most of Jordan is located in UTM zone 37N and only Aqaba area is located in UTM 36N, which in this case will not be a big deformation.
- The last option is you can use [EPSG:3066](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ed50-jordan-tm/) Jordan TM coordinating reference system (CRS) which is a custom UTM CRS that fit Jordan in one zone.

The choice is up to you whether you want to use UTM to follow the standard CRS or local CRS which is Jordan TM CRS.